# swiftでCoreMotionフレームワークをimportしたい

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

swiftDocsのCoreMotionのサンプル( https://sites.google.com/a/gclue.jp/swift-docs/ni-yinki100-ios/5-coremotion/001-jia-su-dusensano-zhiwo-qu-de )をコピペして動かしてみようとしたのですが、importの段階でエラーが出てしまいます。
エラーメッセージは

```
Cannot load module 'coremotion' as 'CoreMotion'
```

となっています。

設定のLinked Frameworks and LibraryでCoreMotion.frameworkはすでに追加済みです。
Xcodeの再起動等を試しても解決はしませんでした。

環境は
Xcode - version 7.0 beta
iphone - ios version 8.3

となっています。
エラーを取るにはどうしたら良いでしょうか。ご教授下さい。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

私もご紹介のリンク先のコードを、Xcode 7betaのプロジェクトにコピー&ペーストしてみましたが、おっしゃるようなエラーメッセージは出ませんでした。なお、Xcode 7betaは先週beta2がリリースされており、私はそれをインストールしてあります。beta2のリビジョンは「7A1211」です。

コードについては、下記の箇所にエラーが出ただけで、書きかえたあと、iPhone 5sにてビルドしたら、問題なく動作しました。

```
// 加速度の取得を開始
myMotionManager.startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue(NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(), withHandler: {(accelerometerData:CMAccelerometerData!, error:NSError!) -> Void in
    myXLabel.text = "x=\(accelerometerData.acceleration.x)"
    myYLabel.text = "y=\(accelerometerData.acceleration.y)"
    myZLabel.text = "z=\(accelerometerData.acceleration.z)"
})
```

**訂正後：**

```
// 「!」を「?」に変更
myMotionManager.startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue(NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(), withHandler: {(accelerometerData:CMAccelerometerData?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
    // Optional Bindingの書式を使う
    if let theData = accelerometerData {
        myXLabel.text = "x=\(theData.acceleration.x)"
        myYLabel.text = "y=\(theData.acceleration.y)"
        myZLabel.text = "z=\(theData.acceleration.z)"
    }
})
```

ということで、Xcode 7betaのアップデートをしたら、解決するのではないかという見方を、私はしています。

Comment: おかげさまで直りました。
しかし、コピペをしただけでは治らずXcodeの示す通りにエラーを消していった所以下の様になりました。  

`// 加速度の取得を開始
        myMotionManager.startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue(NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(), withHandler: {(accelerometerData:CMAccelerometerData?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
            
            myXLabel.text = "x=\(accelerometerData!.acceleration.x)"
            myYLabel.text = "y=\(accelerometerData!.acceleration.y)"
            myZLabel.text = "z=\(accelerometerData!.acceleration.z)"
        })`
  
解決することはできましたので、ありがとうございました。

Comment: すみません、Optional Bindingの部分`if theData = accelerometerData`を`if let theData = accelerometerData`に訂正しました。`let`を抜かしていました。「!」は、もし`accelerometerData`が`nil`だった場合、プログラムがクラッシュするので、お勧めできません。